# How can I control browser back button and page refresh in my angular-cli component

Tags: angular, angular-cli

What I want to achieve is when user is logged in, he must be prompted if he wants to stay logged in or leave. If he wishes to stay logged in, there is no routing. But if he clicks the option labeled *leave* then he must be routed back to the login page. I followed [the sample I saw on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sRNxfXsbcWnPU818aZsu?p=preview). But whenever I tried to click logout, I am not able to route to login page.

[image]

Comment: I followed http://plnkr.co/edit/sRNxfXsbcWnPU818aZsu?p=preview

Comment: Please enter code directly rather then pasting an images of it. Also edit more information into the question, do not enter them to the comments (they are there for discussion & suggestions from others mostly).